# How to write a subquery using the outer table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to write an MySQL query that gets the number of accounts, number of new accounts and number of old accounts per each month.
the condition of an old account is described as cond1.

I've tried:

```
select month(a.ct) as month,
count(select id from a where cond1) as oldAccount,
count(select id from a where !cond1) as newAccount
from accounts a
where ~conditions~
group by month(a.ct)
```

It doesn't work exactly.

In general, I need to know how to use the outer-table in sub-queries.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `count()` would go *inside* the subquery:

```
select month(a.ct) as month,
      (select count(id) from a where cond1) as oldAccount,
      (select count(id) from a where !cond1) as newAccount
from accounts a
where ~conditions~
group by month(a.ct);
```

However, you have an aggregation in the outer query, so this is a bit more complicated.  Your correlation condition is -- presumably -- on the id rather than on the month.  This inconsistency would affect the above query.

The best way is probably to express this as a `join`, but that could depend on the conditions.  Otherwise, you can use a subquery:

```
select month(a.ct) as month,
       sum(oldAccount), sum(newAccount)
from (select a.*,
             (select count(id) from a where cond1) as oldAccount,
             (select count(id) from a where !cond1) as newAccount
      from accounts a
      where ~conditions~
     ) t
group by month(a.ct);
```

EDIT:

If by `a`, you intend the outer `accounts` table, then just use conditional aggregation:

```
select month(a.ct) as month,
      sum(cond1) as oldAccount,
      sum(!cond1) as newAccount
from accounts a
where ~conditions~
group by month(a.ct);
```

Comment: It says that table a does not exists.

Comment: @AntonCool . . . Use the edited version.  The `a` is in your question and I misunderstood its use.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make an inlayed construction when you count if statements that result in `NOT NULL`.
In other words. `IF(condition, 1, NULL)` is evaluated to 1 if condition=true and in `NUL`L otherwise. `COUNT` function counts `NOT NULL` inputs and gives the result.
You may replace `a.ac=0`/`a.ac=1` with any other conditions.

```
SELECT
    month(a.ct)AS month,
    (count(if(a.ac=0,1,NULL)))AS oldAccount,
    (count(if(a.ac=1,1,NULL)))AS newAccount
FROM
    accounts a

GROUP BY
    month(a.ct)
```